# Game crashes on start-up

Tags: no-mans-sky

I'm running an AMD R9 280x and Phenom II X4 965 which from what I can tell meets the minimum specs to run this title. Windows and my video card are up to date. But, my game still crashes on start-up every single time, before it ever makes it to the title screen. I have an error in the event log with the following text if that helps at all:

```
Faulting application name: NMS.exe, version: 0.1.0.0, time stamp: 0x57ade3e9
Faulting module name: NMS.exe, version: 0.1.0.0, time stamp: 0x57ade3e9
Exception code: 0xc000001d
Fault offset: 0x00000000000010b6
Faulting process id: 0x1424
Faulting application start time: 0x01d1f513bc1202f7
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\No Man's Sky\Binaries\NMS.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\No Man's Sky\Binaries\NMS.exe
Report Id: 9bacc1f2-db6e-4ac4-a598-ee8e7965bf9b
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Can anyone shed some light on this problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Make sure you meet minimum specifications to run the game

As per [Sean](https://twitter.com/NoMansSky/status/764166088577851392) [Murray's](https://twitter.com/NoMansSky/status/764166254550618112) [tweets](https://twitter.com/NoMansSky/status/764166411899904000), if you are experiencing crashing, please do the following first:

- Many players are missing Visual C++ Redist 2010. Make sure your game is updated, as as of August 12, 2016, they've issued a patch to address this problem.
- Make sure you have the latest graphics drivers installed for your video card
- Make sure your graphics card is above the minimum specifications because OpenGL 4.5 is required. Many older cards do not support OpenGL 4.5.

**If, despite not meeting minimum specifications, you still want to try to run the game, you can try the following. Please note some of this is at your own risk, as some of it is player created workarounds rather than official developer support**

### Use the experimental build to work around the SSE 4.1 specification

You have the same processor as I do, so you're likely suffering from the same crash, where I'm presuming it shows the "Hello Games" screen and crashes there.

Apparently older CPUs, especially AMD ones, do not support SSE 4.1 CPU instructions, and they are required for the game, which was [confirmed on reddit via emulation](https://www.reddit.com/r/NoMansSkyTheGame/comments/4xene1/pc_crash_thread/d6eyr23?context=3). Currently, the only solution is to use the experimental branch they created to resolve this.

[The experimental branch of the game is now live](https://steamcommunity.com/app/275850/discussions/7/360672304897578119/)

In order to access it, do the following:

1. Navigate to the game in the **Library** menu and right click to access **Properties**
2. Click on the **Betas** tab
3. You'll see a field which says "Enter beta access code to unlock private betas", enter `3xperimental`
4. In the "Select the beta you would like to op into" dropdown, you should see the **Experimental** field now available, click it
5. Start the game

This fixed my crash on startup problem and I was able to successfully get past the Hello Games splash screen. I was able to get to a screen where I was in colorful space with what I assumed were planets flying by, which a friend informed me was the loading screen. However, I experienced a crash to desktop without error upon what I assume would have been the game properly loading.

### Work around the OpenGL 4.5 requirement for graphics cards with the GLIntercept program

Using instructions I found [on this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/NoMansSkyTheGame/comments/4xk0od/fix_for_video_card_without_opengl_45/), by redditor slyther55, I found the GLIntercept program with another fix attempt. If you want to try this, do the following:

1. Install the 64 bit version of GLIntercept, which you can download [here](https://github.com/dtrebilco/glintercept/releases/download/1.3.3/GLInterceptx64_1_3_3.exe)
2. Copy the file `OpenGL32.dll` from installation folder for GLIntercept, which is located by default at `C:\Program Files\GLInterceptx64_1_3_3` to the `Binaries` folder for No Man's Sky. My folder is located at `D:\Games\Steam\steamapps\common\No Man's Sky\Binaries`, as I have the Steam version. If you have a DRM free version you installed elsewhere, adjust the path accordingly.
3. Download this custom `gliconfig.ini` created by the user [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17900579/gliConfig.ini) (**Rightclick** -> **Save Link As...** is easiest)
4. Copy `gliconfig.ini` to the same No Man's Sky `Binaries` folder

**IMPORTANT:** If you install GLIntercept somewhere besides `C:\Program Files\GLInterceptx64_1_3_3\`, you will need to edit `gliconfig.ini` by hand in order to make sure it's pointing at the right path. There are 3 locations in the file you will have to change.

The user hand edited the .ini file to disable logging, add all OpenGL extensions, and ovveride the OpenGL and Shader version languages to 4.5.

I attempted this, and apparently it has allowed many people with my same video card (AMD Radeon HD 6970) to play the game. However, I was still experiencing crashing, did more research and found that I missed that AMD Phenom chipsets donot support "Supplemental SSE 3", which is required for the Havok physics engine. Thus:

### Workaround for AMD Phenom chipsets for SSSE3 requirements

Remember the emulation I mentioned earlier? Apparently, [using the experimental build combined with the emulation allowed this redditor to run the game successfully](https://www.reddit.com/r/NoMansSkyTheGame/comments/4xene1/pc_crash_thread/d6gsg4u). Said user has the same CPU as we do, stated here:

> I'm running on a Phenom II x4 965 black edition 3400Mhz processor in Win10 with 16GB RAM using an AMD Radeon R7 370 series graphics card.

Said problem was also posted about [here](https://steamcommunity.com/app/275850/discussions/1/360672137535529618/?ctp=72#c360672304897793884) on Steam.

So now we need to run the emulator, going back to [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/NoMansSkyTheGame/comments/4xene1/pc_crash_thread/d6eyr23?context=3). Make sure you're already running the experimental build.

1. Download the emulator [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/pre-release-license-agreement-for-intel-software-development-emulator-accept-end-user-license-agreement-and-download). Choose the one for Windows, accept the Terms and Conditions, and download the file called `sde-external-7.49.0-2016-07-07-win.tar.bz2`, size 13.91MB.
2. Extract it (it's packaged 3 times, so you'll have to extract 3 times) and copy *all* files and folders to the NMS `Binaries` folder
3. Create a shortcut of `sde.exe` within the same folder
4. **Rightclick** the shortcut (**not** the original) and go to **Properties**
5. In the **Target:** field, you'll see the path in quotation marks. For example, mine is `"D:\Games\Steam\steamapps\common\No Man's Sky\Binaries\sde.exe"`. At the end, **outside** of the quotation marks, insert a space, then append `-- NMS.exe`. The resulting target should look like `"D:\Games\Steam\steamapps\common\No Man's Sky\Binaries\sde.exe" -- NMS.exe`
6. Click on the **Compatibility** tab. Check the box near the bottom that says **Run this program as an administrator**
7. Run the newly edited `sde.exe - Shortcut`, which should theoretically now allow you to run the game

**NOTE** You may receive an error that says the following:

> Either Steam isn't running or you don't have a suitable licence
>   If this happens, follow these steps:

1. In the NMS `Binaries` folder once again, **create a text file** named `steam_appid.txt`
2. Type `275850` inside and **Save** and close the file
3. Try again. If it doesn't work, remove the `.txt` after `steam_appid` and try again, in case hidden extensions in Windows are making it so the file is called `steam_appid.txt.txt`.

I started the emulator, and it got to the loading screen and was there for about 5 minutes, then the white screen came, and **finally**, the game started up with *Initializing* showing. Make sure you hold down <kbd>E</kbd>, not just tap it.

I had previously experienced a problem with the Radeon 16.2 beta drivers where I had a black background instead of terrain. Rolling back to the 15.7 drivers fixed this for me.

As of the August 18th, 2016 patch, the game is now running for me and I am successfully playing it, using the experimental build and the OpenGL 4.5 workaround. I don't appear to need the emulation anymore, which vastly improves game performance!

Comment: So I guess just some waiting. I imagine they'll fix it as soon as they can now that they know the issue.

Comment: @spugsley Pretty much. I _think_ our CPUs are technically below min spec though either way. I'm not entirely sure, as the AMD equivalent min spec equivalent is not listed on any of the digital distribution platforms the game is released on, so that's something to keep in mind. I'm personally upgrading my PC anyway within the next few weeks anyway because I was due for one, but that option isn't exactly available for everyone.

Comment: are you able to play the game now or does it just get you past the splash screen? I'm seeing people have mixed results

Comment: @spugsley I'm finally ingame. After a lot of **multiple expletives deleted** trial and error. Now I just have to figure out why I have a black screen, except for the UI, which works just fine. At least it's not crashing anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Experimental branch has gone live, see https://steamcommunity.com/app/275850/discussions/7/360672304897578119/ for info.

I've the same problem as you, except I'm running a Phenom 2 x6 1055T.

Before trying Experimental I'd get the HelloGames logo then a crash and nearly the same event log.

After enabling Experimental, I'll get past the logo and into an intro movie, followed by immediately dropping back to Steam/Windows desktop with no errors in the Event Viewer.

Comment: same issue, I start flying through stars with names but then it drops, no error message or clue. I've got a Phenom II x4 B40, guessing it's a remaining SSE issue and we'll have to wait to see if further patching/experimentation covers it.